# scroll % of the screen

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

- How to detect if the user scrolls 50% of the screen with jQuery?. (Here I can say if it scrolls 50px)
- Then, animate and go to #second or, what is the same, top 100% (it seems that it animates but something estrange happens)

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/NH6Km/2/

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function(){   
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) { 
    ('body,html').animate({ scrollTop:             
    $('#second').offset().top }, 1500); 
  } 
});     
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#first{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:blue;
} 
#second{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: So, when the user begins to scroll, you want to interrupt their scrolling and scroll for them to the next div. correct?

Comment: I try to animate to the next/prev div if it is in the middle. It could be when the user begins to scroll or perhaps better when he finish to scroll?

Comment: How do you know if it's in the middle? (easy answer). Detect when the scroll stops, then if it's in the middle, scroll to the closer of the two.

Comment: @Kevin B. Yes this is it. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: with javascript and a scroll event. you'll also need a setTimeout. If you don't want to write it yourself, search for it in pieces and put the pieces together.

Comment: Why the negative point? If I know I can solve it

Comment: possibly *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*

Answer (score 0):

As @thecodedestroyer said, you can use the scroll event to do something like this:

```
var currentDiv = "#first";
var divArray = ["#first", "#second", "#third", "#fourth"];

$(window).on("scroll", function (e) {
    var ix = divArray.indexOf(currentDiv);
    if (ix >= 0) {
        if (window.pageYOffset > $(currentDiv).offset().top) {
            currentDiv = divArray[(ix + 1) % currentDiv.length];
        } else if (window.pageYOffset < $(currentDiv).offset().top) {
            currentDiv = divArray[(ix - 1) % currentDiv.length];
        }
        $("body, html").animate({
            scrollTop: $(currentDiv).offset().top
        }, 0);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here a test:
http://jsfiddle.net/cxJQE/

Answer (score -1):

Use the scroll event http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
when event is triggered use this plugin http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html